# Want to create a custom class XY that inherits from a Class and a Protocol

Tags: class, protocols, swift3, xcode8, watchos-3

I want to create the `AVAudioInputNode` in watchOS 3.

If I click on JumpToDefinition for `AVAudioInputNode`, I see that:

```
open class AVAudioInputNode : AVAudioIONode, AVAudioMixing {
}
```

Why I can't create a custom class with the same style ?

My class is:

```
open class xy : AVAudioIONode, AVAudioMixing {
}
```

The error is

> Type xy does not conform to protocol "AvAudioMixing" and "AVAudioStereoMixing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you need to conform to those 2 protocols, that means you need to apply specific functions or properties that those protocols requiere.

For Example, for table views on a UIViewController Class you use 2 protocols: UITablewViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource. And to conform those protocols you need to use this functions.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> int {
return 1 
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tablewView.dequehueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "weatherCell", for: indexPath)
  return cell
}
```

And also assign its delegate and Data source:

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

In the specific case of those 2 protocols AVAudioIONode, AVAudioMixing you should search which are the required functions you need to conform.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
class XY : AVAudioIONode, AVAudioMixing { ... }
```

That means that that

- you're subclassing `AVAudioIONode`, but also that
- that you're going to conform to the [`AVAudioMixing`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiomixing) protocol (i.e. that you'll implement the necessary `AVAudioMixing` methods/properties), as well as any protocols that `AVAudioMixing` inherits (e.g. [`AVAudioStereoMixing`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiostereomixing)).

So, your error is telling you that while you've declared that your class will conform to `AVAudioMixing` (and therefore `AVAudioStereoMixing`, too), you haven't yet implemented the necessary methods and properties. The compiler is just warning you that you haven't finished implementing `XY` in order to successfully conform to those protocols.